# Zero knowledge RSA public key

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, zero-knowledge-proofs

Suppose Bob has $k>1$ RSA public keys $(e_i, n_i)$ without any knowledge of their corresponding private keys. Alice also has all the public keys, but also has a private key for only one of them, say, $(d_j, n_j)$. Is it possible for her to prove to Bob that she has at least one of the private keys, without revealing $j$

EDIT: changed notation according to fgrieu suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is even possible without interaction (nothing Bob needs to send to Alice). The method is called "ring signature".

Let's say she wants to sign a message like "I am Alice an hereby proof to Bob that I know one of the keys".
She hashes it to get $m$.

Alice now generates a random value $r_i$ for every public key $k_i$ and encrypts them to get $y_i$.

Note that they all $y_i$ are unpredictable pseudorandom values. The only $y_i$ she can choose is the one that belongs to her key $k_j$, she just chooses $y_j$ and sign it to get $r_j$ ($r_j$ looks like every other random data)

Now  she can choose $y_j$ so that the xor of all $y_i$ equals $m$.

She sends the message and all the $r_i$ to Bob (if the order is not clear, add a note which $r_i$ belongs to which key)

To verify, Bob just encrypts every $r_i$ with the public key $k_i$ to get the $y_i$, xors them all and checks if it equals $m$.

Since all $y_i$ are like random numbers, when you don't know the key, there is no way to fake a signature without knowing a private key.
Additionally there is no way to tell which $y_i$ and $r_i$ was not randomly generated, because they all look random.

Important EDIT:
I forgot the symmetric encryption step in the ring signature. Between the xor steps symmetric encryption should be applied. This still allows allice to recover the $y_i$ she needs, but makes attacks harder.
For more details look at [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_signature)

Comment: @fgrieu I changed the names von $e$ to $y$, thanks for that. You can just choose by xor-ing all other $y_i$ and $m$ to get $y_j$. There is no need for trial and error when you know the private key of $k_j$. The length problem can easily be fixed by limiting the bits to xor to the number of bits in m and ignore the others

Comment: Yes, masking out enough high order bits (just one if the $n_i$ are the same bit size) makes it possible to avoid any trial and error. Again, how the high order bit(s) of $y_j$ is chosen requires careful consideration.

Comment: When the hash is $h$-bit, I'm [told](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/92216/555) there is an [attack](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-45708-9_19) of cost $\mathcal O(2^{h/(1+\log_2(k))})$, which can get worrying for large $k$. On another front, I find it non-trivial to prevent an adversary from gaining some (little) advantage on guessing $j$, especially when $h$ approaches the width of the smallest $n_i$.

Comment: @fgrieu Ok, I checked and noticed that I did not remember the algorithm correctly. The base Idea is still correct. I added a note to my answer. Thanks for checking. I still think ring signatures are really good for this problem

Comment: Yes, ring signature works for this. But a critical detail is missing in the Wikipedia article and the answer: the domain for the $r_i$ and $y_i$ must be made the same size even though the $n_i$ are different, in order to prevent leak of information about $j$. This is addressed in the [Extending trap-door permutations to a common domain](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-45682-1_32.pdf#page=6) section of the Rivest-Shamir-Tauman paper.

Comment: @jjj this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proposal (out of my head). Big picture

- Bob draws a random $X$, and sends it deterministically enciphered under each public key
- Alice deciphers $X$ with the public key she holds
- Alice checks Bob did as expected given that $X$
- Alice reveals $X$ to Bob

---

More precisely:

- Define a $8b$-bit hash (say SHA-512) such that $\min(n_i)>2^{16b}$
- Define a Mask Generation Function (such as [MGF1](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#page=50) with that hash) so that for bytestring $X$, $\operatorname{MGF}(X,\ell)$ is an $\ell$-byte hash of $X$
- Define the byte lengths $\ell_i=\left\lfloor\log_2(n_i)/8\right\rfloor$, which are such that $2^{8\ell_i}<n_i<2^{8\ell_i+8}$ (in order to avoid timing attacks, it's desirable that the $n_i$ have the same bit size, thus the $l_i$ equal)
- Bob draws a random $X\in\{0,1\}^{8b}$ (a $b$-byte bytestring)
- For each $i$, Bob

  - computes $M_i=\operatorname{MGF}\bigl(X\mathbin\|H(n_i),l_i-b\bigr)$
  - computes $X_i=M_i\mathbin\|(X\oplus H(M_i\mathbin\|H(n_i)))$ (an $l_i$-byte bytestring)
  - computes and output $C_i={X_i}^{e_i}\bmod n_i$
- Alice gets the $C_i$, including $C_j$
- Alice computes $f={C_j}^{d_j}\bmod n_j$
- Alice expresses $f$ as bytestring $M\mathbin\|G$ with $M$ of $l_i-b$ bytes and $G$ of $b$ bytes.
- Alice recovers $X$ by computing $X=G\oplus H(M\mathbin\|J)$
- For each $i$, Alice

  - computes $M_i=\operatorname{MGF}\bigl(X\mathbin\|H(n_i),l_i-b\bigr)$, where $I$ is index $i$ as a bytestring.
  - computes $X_i=M_i\mathbin\|(X\oplus H(M_i\mathbin\|H(n_i)))$ (an $l_i$-byte bytestring)
  - checks ${X_i}^{e_i}\bmod n_i=C_i$ (when $i=j$, this checks $M=\operatorname{MGF}\bigl(X\mathbin\|H(n_j),l_j-b\bigr)$ as a side effect)
- Only if all the checks passed, and without revealing (e.g. by timing) where an error occurred if any, or which $X_i$ was used to recover $X$

  - Alice reveals $X$
- Bob checks Alice revealed the right $X$

Rationale:

- Alice proves she can decipher one of the cryptograms $C_i$, thus that she holds a private key
- She does not reveal which, since she verified all the cryptograms match the same $X$. There is no risk that a bias in the high-order bits in some quantity in $[0,n_j)$ can give an advantage in guessing $j$ (as could be the case in a naive implementation of [that other answer](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#page=16)).
- Representatives $X_i$ of $X$ are spread on $[0,n_i)$ as in [RSASSA-OAEP](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#page=16), with independent padding functions. Notice that directly enciphering $X_i=X$, or $X_i=F(X)$ for some fixed injection $F$, would leave the system vulnerable to [Håstad's broadcast attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%27s_attack#H%C3%A5stad%27s_broadcast_attack); further, it could be impossible to define a safe common width for the $X_i$, e.g. if $n_0$ is 2048-bit, $n_1$ 8192-bit, $e_1=3$; the padding solves that.
- Since $X$ is a challenge drawn by Bob, the protocol is immune to replay: Alice can't get away with data she precomputed before loosing access to her private key, or data previously computed by Amanda, who also holds a private key.

---

Possible improvements to further guard Alice from becoming a decryption oracle, Bob from tweaking its $X$, and perhaps make a proof easier:

- Alice first draws $b$-byte $Y$ and sends a commitment $H(Y\mathbin\|S_0)$
- Bob draws its $b$-byte $X$ and sends a commitment $H(X\mathbin\|S_1)$
- Alice reveals $Y$, Bob checks it against $H(Y\mathbin\|0)$
- the above protocol is modified

  - it's used $M_i=\operatorname{MGF}\bigl(X\mathbin\|Y\mathbin\|H(n_i),l_i-b\bigr)$
  - it's used $X_i=M_i\mathbin\|(X\oplus H(M_i\mathbin\|Y\mathbin\|H(n_i)))$
  - Alice further checks $H(X\mathbin\|1)$ matches
  - Alice reveals $H(X\mathbin\|S_2)$ rather than $X$
  - Bob checks that.
    (where the $S_i$ are distinct arbitrary short non-empty bytestrings)

---

Update: Another method, outlined in [this other answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/92203/555), is to use an [RSA-based ring signature](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-45682-1_32), and make Alice demonstrate to Bob her capacity to sign a challenge message.

Comment: There is no need for Bob to draw anything. Alice can do it. To prevent Alice from choosing instead of drawing, one can just use a hash of a message she publishes.

Comment: @jjj: your suggestion makes the protocol vulnerable to replay. See new fourth bullet in the rationale.

Comment: Not necessarily, it depends on the message that is hashed. One can just include a nonce.